# Why isn't this perl cgi script redirecting?

Tags: perl, cgi, qnx

I have a perl cgi script that is exactly the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
$query = new CGI;
print $query->redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");
```

At the command line things look OK:

```
$perl test.pl
Status: 302 Moved
Location: http://www.yahoo.com
```

When I load it in the browser, `http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.pl`, the request gets aborted, and depending on the browser I get various messages:

- Connection reset by server.
- No data received.

The only research I could find on this issue, stated that a common problem is printing some data or header before the redirect call, but I am clearly not doing that here.

I'm hosting it from a QNX box with the default slinger server.

Comment: Are there any error messages in your web server logs?

Comment: Can you test it using the shebang: `./test.pl` ?  Namely, is the shebang set correctly, and is the file's chmod correct ?

Comment: What status does your web server show for that request in the access log? What does the web browser return to the client (as seen using Firebug, for example)? Does `http://www.yahoo.com/` work better than `http://www.yahoo.com`?

Answer (score 2):

The code works fine on my machine, check the following

- Check the error logs, eg: tail /var/log/http/error_log
- Do the chmod/chown permissions match other working CGi scripts, compare using ls -l
- Does printing the standard hello world work?  Change your print statement to

  ```
  print $query->header(), 'Hello World';
  ```
- Add the following for better errors

  ```
  use warnings;
  use diagnostics;
  use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';
  ```

Comment: Adding the better error statements was a good idea, but it didn't change the behavior.  Replacing the print statement works just fine for printing out Hello World to the browser.  I don't have log files in that location, I'm trying to figure out if logging is off and/or where the log file is actually written to on this machine.

Comment: What web server are you using? Check to see if your server stack is overriding 300 responses. Try this redirect alternative as well;print $cgi->header(-location => "http://yahoo.com");

Answer (score 0):

at the command line `use slinger` will return some basic use options. For logging you need both syslogd and -d enabled in slinger. Ie
slinger -d &
Then look to /var/log/syslog for errors